# SQLSTATE[00000] [1040] Too many connections with Max_used_connections of 1001

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, connection

Yesterday everything was working fine. I send out the link to the PHP application to the customer. A few hours later I looked on to the page and saw in the source code the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[00000] [1040] Too many connections
```

I also log the errors and only see the above message.

In the PHP application there are many request but only to one specific table (no joins ...). I also use an own class for the database connection. Therein I have a handle which is set if has not been set before.

```
if($this->_handle == null){
    $this->Connect();
}
try{
    // make query
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "An error occured: {$e->getMessage()}";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}
```

So there shouldn't be something like a new connection each request. But I never close the connection (don't know where I should close it).

1. Is a new connection made for each user or is the same connection used for multiple users?
2. How can I check in the code if a connection is available and present the user a corresponding message instead of displaying a malicious page?
3. Is something wrong with my code that too many connections are used?
4. How can I log if a successfull connection is made?

This is my Connect function:

```
public function Connect(){
    try{
        $this->_handle = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->dbhost};dbname={$this->dbname}", $this->dbuser, $this->dbpasswd);
        $this->_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "An error occured: {$e->getMessage()}";
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage() . chr(10) . chr(13), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```

Than I tried to search the internet after this error. This is what I found out:

MySQL Server 5.0.77 -> [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/too-many-connections.html)

PHP 5.2.9 with locked phpinfo()

`show variables like 'max_connections';` gives me 1000!

If I use `SHOW STATUS;` I see the following:

```
Aborted_clients         16
Aborted_connects        15248
Connections             1694699
Max_used_connections    1001
Queries                 266398903
Table_locks_immediate   36136077
Table_locks_waited      40387
Threads_connected       2
Threads_created         1694698
Threads_running         2
Uptime                  2143256
```

1. I don't think I have reached this number of queries in a day so is this a shared host?
2. What Can I do against the too many connections problem?

Currently everything is working fine now, but I don't want this problem if the system goes live and much more users will use it.

Comment: Do you close connection too? http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Nope, I never close the connection. I don't know where it should be done. If I would do it in index.php or in a function, than I would get open/close all the time. Don't know if this is better than now. Do you have a suggestion?